# Download PyPi package manualy with all dependencies (without PIP)

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I am not able to use PIP on this device, so I need to install a module manually. The only problem is that I have to install like 30 dependencies of this module. I would have to download, unzip, include and install them all one by one.

Is there any faster way, like downloading a module with all its dependencies included?

Comment: That's going to be very challenging. Your 30 dependencies may further depend on other packages, and there may be dependency versions requirements that you'll need to resolve manually. A better question may be why can't you use pip?

Comment: Is `pip` available, but the device is offline?  `pip` can download a package and all its dependencies via `pip download <package>`, then move them to the device and use `pip --no-index --find-links . <package>` to prevent pip from looking for PyPI and only look in the current directory for installation packages.

Answer (score 0):

If all requirements are pip packages, a quick solution might involve creating a lean python environment on another machine, installing the package using pip, and then copying over all of the resultant wheel files to the restricted machine either via SSH or another method.